# Complexity of Prims using Array

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, graph-algorithm, prims-algorithm

The complexity of Prims Algorithm using Array and Adjacency List is:

> `V^2 + V + 2E + E = O(V^2)`

But, I can't recall why `E`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity using an adjacency list structure for graph representation, and an array for a priority queue, is *Θ(|V|<sup>2</sup> + |E|)*. For graphs without parallel edges, this is *Θ(|V|<sup>2</sup>)*.

Prim's algorithm works in *|V|* iterations, growing a tree starting with size 1 and ending with size *|V|*. Say at some iteration, vertex *v* is added to the tree, and lete *E(v)* be the edges emanating from *v*. For each such edge, we can find the neighbor in the array, and update the lightest distance from some vertex in the current tree to it. Finding the vertex *v* takes time *Θ(|V|)*, as we must scan the array to find the minimum (it's an inefficient implementation of a priority queue).

Altogether, each edge is accessed once in each direction (hence *Θ(|E|)*, and each of the *|V|* iteration does a *Θ(|V|)* scan on the array.

---

Note that for your expression in the question, *V^2+V+2E+E*, it's important to recall that the context is a consideration of orders of growth. Hence there's not much meaning to *2E* (what does the 2 stand for? iterating twice over the edges? The number of CPU instructions per edge?) or indeed to *2E + E*. These are just vague shorthand notations used sometimes to indicate the various stages in the algorithm.

Comment: 2E is the iteration over Adj list because you will find a single edge two times, so 2E, but asymtotically it's E.